# How does WEKA code the value of an instance as a double value

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

When we want to read a particular value of an instance we use the following method:

```
public double value(int attIndex)
```

Now, how do I get back to the original value from the double value? Is it possible to know what datatype is this particular value, and if I already know if it of type String, how can I get the String value?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanto to get the String value you can use

```
public double stringValue(int attIndex)
```